# Gap between house and wood deck -- to fill or not to fill?

Tags: deck, gap

I have a low free-standing deck that keeps accumulating debris like leaves between the house and the deck, about a one-inch gap. Is it possible or advisable to fill this gap with something? Maybe like Great Stuff?

The length of the deck along the house is about 20 feet, and the deck is basically is resting on the ground like a big glorified wooden step.

Comment: Even if you filled it in wouldn't debris still accumulate there? At least now, some of it falls through to the ground. I have a free standing deck right up against the wall and I'm cleaning stuff away all the time.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Don't use Great Stuff as an outdoor material; it won't last. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Thanks! Just seemed like to narrow of a gap to clean effectively or easily, and too wide to avoid some bigger debris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the reason why a floating deck "works" is that it is **not** attached to the house in any way. If you put in something that physically connects the deck to the house, even Great Stuff, you will end up with one of two possibilities:

- Stays together when the deck moves

If the deck and the house stay together when the deck moves then you will be twisting the deck platform and/or supports, which is not a good thing and could lead to serious problems.

- Does NOT stay together when the deck moves

If the deck and the house do not stay together when the moves, then the connection will break - which would mean your time/effort/$ would go to waste.

Floating decks move. That is **why** they are allowed to be built (in most places, up to a certain size) without a permit and also why they are specifically **not** to be attached to any fixed structure.

What can you do? I suggest adding a piece of wood trim to fill the gap but attach it **only** to the deck.